How can I calculate the user session time in data dog
I need to calculate the user session time in Datadog from the log.
In logs, I have the content for

login success is "User login success"
logout success is "User logout sucess"

I want to calculate the duration between 2 logs with the session_id and sort it. I have research for some queries but didn't find any that meet the condition. In addition, I have used the Transactions group by but it can not sort with the DURATION field and cannot create the metric.
Please help me.
